# access to phone's settings : codeName one

Tags: codenameone

I would like to know if it's possible to access my phone settings using CodeNameOne. For example, if I want to get my EMEI( International Mobile Equiment Identity) or the serial number of my phone, is there a way to get it using codeNameOne?
If yes how ? if not, what alternative can I use?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have `Display.getMsisdn()` & `Display.getUdid()` but those only work on Android and produce scary looking permission prompts.

Since this is Android specific it would make sense to code EMEI & similar calls with a native interface anyway.